# python script to automatically write a text file

Tags: python, input, automation, ascii, output

I use a algorithm that is created on an ASCII file, so usually i have to start from scratch to write the commands by hand.

I am thinking of utilizing python's ability to make the process automated.
the final ASCII file has multiple lines with every section being a separate command, with a specific set of standard and additional option after that

My question is how can i start writing something like that. I have been using the ability of python to output files from data manipulation but using multiple lines seems new to me.

The objective is for python to automatically write a specific length of words and then having request from the user to input numbers or word to be filled in at specified place.

my file goes something like this, with CAPITAL letters are the standard write commands while with 'CAPITAL' or 'NUMBER' the set of options i want to input.

```
PROJECT 'name' 'nr'
SET 'maxerr' 'cdcap' 'inhorg' 'hserr' 'NAUTICAL or CARTESIAN' 'pwtail'
MODE NONSTATIONARY 'TWODIMENSIONAL or ONEDIMENSIONAL'  

.....(the list goes on)

COMPUTE NONSTAT 'starting date input' 'time interval' 'ending date input'
STOP
```

the thing i have in mind when i run the script is to be like this

```
enter name of project =
enter number of project

enter maxerr =  (if no maxerr is entered then proceed to the next input, without writing MAXERR in the file)
```

My objective is to have terminal ask the user to input a value or string which after will be written and incorporated in the final file, with the results being something like this.

```
PROJECT 'myname' '1'
SET MAXERR 200 INHORG 1 HSERR 0.9 NAUTICAL PWTAIL 2
MODE NONSTATIONARY ONEDIMENSIONAL
........
COMPUTE 20100101.000000 1 HR 20100102.0000
STOP
```

thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing multiple lines to a file is not particularly different from writing a single line. A line is terminated by a newline character, `"\n"`, and everything that follows that character is on the next line.

So:

```
f = open("outfile.txt", "w")
f.write("First ")  # No newline, line continues
f.write("line")  
f.write("\n")      # Line ends!
f.write("Second line\n")  # Newline character in the same write
f.close()
```

You can also call other functions in between:

```
f = open("outfile.txt", "w")
f.write("User input: ")
user_input = raw_input("Your input? ")
f.write(user_input)
f.write("\n")
f.close()
```

This should allow you to at least attempting a solution to your problem. Good luck! :-)

Comment: You should generally recommend use of the `with` context manager for handling files these (post-Python 2.5) days: `with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as f:`.

Comment: @JorgenSchafer, thank you very much in the second proposal for the writing of quantities, can i use user_input=raw_input("Your input?") and f.write(SET+" user_input,'w') , correct?

Comment: jonrsharpe, indeed; I thought about it, but I figured the user is very new to Python and I did not want to overwhelm them with new concepts.

Comment: George, you mean `f.write("SET " + user_input)` – and yes, you can do that. `raw_input` returns a normal string, and `write` takes a string. See the [standard library documentation for raw_input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) for details.

Comment: @JorgenSchäfer yes thank you very much, i am a bit of a new user so i am trying to test out several things that i have seen that python can do , thank you both for the help

Comment: You are welcome. And enjoy Python! You are doing the exact right thing: Find small problems to solve and learn through practice. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
f1 = open("read.txt", "r")
f11 = f1.readlines()
f = open("write.txt", "a+")
 for i in f11:
    f.write(str(i))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: In "f1" have to send the (.txt file) path.In "f" have to give the path of the File Destination with Desire name (.txt file).In "f" the path automatically create the desire (.txt file).The f.write(str(i)) it will append the Data of information from "f1" path to "f" desire (.txt file).